# How to change the MaxDegreeOfParallelism of an existing TPL block?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have created a small pipeline with the TPL Dataflow. It is composed of a `TransformBlock` linked to an `ActionBlock`. Here is how the setup looks like:

```
var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, string>(async num=>
{
    //  Do stuff.
    return num.ToString();
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
});

var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(text=>
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
});

transformBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions
{
    PropagateCompletion = true
});
```

I would like to alter the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of the transform block instance. I haven't found a way to do so since there are no public property allowing me to change it. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I am asking the community if it is possible to change these values :) I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: The only possible way is to use reflection and dig deep into the internals of a block. Really there's no good way and it's not recommended.

Comment: @JSteward Changing parameters through Reflection is definitely something I would not do :)

Comment: @Kzrystof but what about changing the parameters through reflection of an actively running parallel processing job?  That's gotta be totally fine, right?

Comment: @Jonesopolis I do not want to bypass Microsoft's encapsulation of these classes.

Comment: As a workaround, (only works to increase parallelism), if there was a Buffer block in between the Transform and Action blocks, an additional Action block with the difference in degree of parallelism required could be added, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions):

> Dataflow block capture the state of the options **at their construction**. Subsequent changes to the provided [ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions) instance **should not affect the behavior of a dataflow block**.

So, answering your question,

> I would like to alter the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of the transform block instance.

It's not intended for existing block to change it's options. You either should create new one or create a new pipeline, or adjust this setting from the beginning to achieve maximum profit.

Answer (score 1):

I made an attempt to solve this problem by using an interchangeable `TransformBlock`, sandwiched between two `BufferBlock`s. Every time the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is changed, the old `TransformBlock` is detached, marked as completed, awaited for its completion, and then a new `TransformBlock` is attached in its place. This solution has two drawbacks:

1. The degree of parallelism is gradually dropping to zero during the intermittent phase of replacing the middle block.
2. The `BoundedCapacity` of the middle block must be set equal to `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, which may affect performance for very granular workloads.

Here is the `CreateVariableDopPropagator` method, and its companion `VariableDopExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` class:

```
public class VariableDopExecutionDataflowBlockOptions : ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    private readonly object _locker = new object();

    public event EventHandler MaxDegreeOfParallelismChanged;

    /// <summary>Gets the maximum number of messages that may be processed by the
    /// block concurrently.</summary>
    public new int MaxDegreeOfParallelism
    {
        get { lock (_locker) return base.MaxDegreeOfParallelism; }
        set
        {
            bool changed;
            lock (_locker)
            {
                changed = value != base.MaxDegreeOfParallelism;
                base.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = value;
            }
            if (changed) MaxDegreeOfParallelismChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public static IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    CreateVariableDopPropagator<TInput, TOutput>(
    Func<TInput, Task<TOutput>> transform,
    VariableDopExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions)
{
    if (transform == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transform));
    if (dataflowBlockOptions == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataflowBlockOptions));

    var optionsCopy = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        BoundedCapacity = dataflowBlockOptions.BoundedCapacity,
        CancellationToken = dataflowBlockOptions.CancellationToken,
        EnsureOrdered = dataflowBlockOptions.EnsureOrdered,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism,
        MaxMessagesPerTask = dataflowBlockOptions.MaxMessagesPerTask,
        NameFormat = dataflowBlockOptions.NameFormat,
        SingleProducerConstrained = dataflowBlockOptions.SingleProducerConstrained,
        TaskScheduler = dataflowBlockOptions.TaskScheduler,
    };

    var locker = new object();
    var input = new BufferBlock<TInput>(optionsCopy);
    var output = new BufferBlock<TOutput>(optionsCopy);
    PropagateFailure(output, input);

    var propagateCompletion = new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true };
    TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput> middle;
    IDisposable link1 = null;
    IDisposable link2 = null;
    CreateMiddleBlock();

    dataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelismChanged += OnMaxDopChanged;
    OnCompletion(output, () =>
    {
        dataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelismChanged -= OnMaxDopChanged;
    }, null);

    return DataflowBlock.Encapsulate(input, output);

    void CreateMiddleBlock()
    {
        IDataflowBlock localMiddle;
        lock (locker)
        {
            link1?.Dispose();
            link2?.Dispose();
            var maxDop = dataflowBlockOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism;
            optionsCopy.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDop;
            optionsCopy.BoundedCapacity = maxDop;
            middle = new TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>(transform, optionsCopy);
            link1 = input.LinkTo(middle, propagateCompletion);
            link2 = middle.LinkTo(output, propagateCompletion);
            localMiddle = middle;
        }
        PropagateFailure(localMiddle, input); // Non disposable link, but it doesn't
        // matter because the completion of the middle must be awaited anyway.
    }

    void OnMaxDopChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Detach the middle block if it's not already detached
        IDataflowBlock localMiddle;
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (link1 == null) return;
            link1.Dispose();
            link2.Dispose();
            link1 = null;
            link2 = middle.LinkTo(output); // Without completion propagation
            localMiddle = middle;
        }
        localMiddle.Complete();
        OnCompletion(localMiddle, () => CreateMiddleBlock(), output);
    }

    async void PropagateFailure(IDataflowBlock block1, IDataflowBlock block2)
    {
        try { await block1.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false); }
        catch (Exception ex) { if (!block1.Completion.IsCanceled) block2.Fault(ex); }
    }

    async void OnCompletion(IDataflowBlock block, Action action, IDataflowBlock onError)
    {
        try { await block.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false); }
        catch { } // Ignore
        finally
        {
            try { action(); }
            catch (Exception ex) { if (onError != null) onError.Fault(ex); else throw; }
        }
    }
}

// Overload with synchronous delegate
public static IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    CreateVariableDopPropagator<TInput, TOutput>(
    Func<TInput, TOutput> transform,
    VariableDopExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions)
{
    return CreateVariableDopPropagator<TInput, TOutput>(
        item => Task.FromResult(transform(item)), dataflowBlockOptions);
}
```

Usage example:

```
private VariableDopExecutionDataflowBlockOptions _options;
private IPropagatorBlock<string, bool> _urlChecker;
private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _options = new VariableDopExecutionDataflowBlockOptions();
    _urlChecker = CreateVariableDopPropagator<string, bool>(async (url) =>
    {
        return (await _client.GetAsync(url)).IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }, _options);
}

private void ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = (int)ListBox1.SelectedValue;
}
```